# Distance for GeoPolygon

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to get the distance between a geopoint (my coordinate) and GeoPolygon indexed property (serviceAreas). Are there any scripting method that does this? I"m using ElasticSearch 6.3.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to be more specific - distance from the `geo_point` to the centroid of a polygon? To the nearest polygon coordinate? To the nearest edge?

Comment: @RussCam I believe to the nearest edge would suffice.